# How to use Compound Controls

Tags: android

I've created a custom ViewGroup based on a LinearLayout.

**ClearableEditText.java**

```
package test.todolist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ClearableEditText extends LinearLayout{
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    public ClearableEditText (Context context){
        super (context);

        String service = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext ().getSystemService (service);
        li.inflate (R.layout.clearable_edit_text, this, true);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.clearEditText);
        button = (Button)findViewById (R.id.clearButton);

        configButton ();
    }

    private void configButton (){
        button.setOnClickListener (new Button.OnClickListener (){
            public void onClick (View v){
                editText.setText ("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**clearable_edit_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/clearEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I use ClearableEditText now?

I've tried to put a node inside a layout (main.xml) in 2 ways:

```
<test.todolist.ClearableEditText/>
```

and

```
<test.todolist.clearable_edit_text/>
```

but none of them have worked.

My **main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test.todolist.ClearableEditText/>
```

My **ToDoList.java** (main activity):

```
package test.todolist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ToDoList extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: First variant must work. Don't you have a typo in a code? `<test.todolist.ClearableEditText/>` instead `<test.toolist.ClearableEditText/>`?

Comment: No :(. Added main ToDoList.java (main activity) and main.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. The main.xml should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <test.todolist.ClearableEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</merge>
```

First, `merge` tag because it is needed when using custom views. My custom view have a `LinearLayout` root, so it's inefficient if I set another LinearLayout or FrameLayout root in main.xml to use my custom view. `merge` solves that.

And second, all views must have the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes.

Comment: Hey, I know that's an old post but first thanks for your post it helped me a lot. Secondly, merge is not required, the xmlns field can be put inside your test.todolist.ClearableEditText.